# VMware guest PXE boot fails and hangs, Can It auto-retry?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, pxe-boot, kickstart

I use Kickstart to build most of my virtual machines which is consistent and repeatable.

However, when I'm building 100+ machines, many times they get stuck mid-install and need a CTRL-Alt-Ins to get going, any ideas on a way to make they auto-retry?  It completely defeats the purpose of using automation if I need to go and find the ones that are stuck and reboot them.

Install files come over apache2(plaintext) reverse proxy to an internal/local mirror(https/internal cert).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you're being sent into dracut emergency shell. If you want to avoid this and just reboot the system when critical problem is encountered just add `rd.shell=0 rd.emergency=reboot` to your kernel command-line.

Add these lines to your kickstart config located in your pxelinux.cfg folder.

```
LABEL centos7_x64_default
MENU LABEL Default CentOS 7 X64
KERNEL /netboot/vmlinuz
APPEND  initrd=/netboot/initrd.img  inst.ks=http://192.168.10.10/default.cfg inst.gpt rd.shell=0 rd.emergency=reboot
```